# Redirect to asp.net page using JQUERY on asp.net button click from ajax modal extendar

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my asp.net application, I will redirect to details.aspx page, which contains OK button. when "ok" button is clicked , i opens a Modal pop up extendar which contains submit and cancel button. On submit button click i am storing data in database on server side coding , after saving data i want to redirect the page into some other page say "Report.aspx". This i do as below,

```
$("[id$=btnQuerySubmit]").bind("click",function () {
    window.location.href = "../web/Report.aspx";
});
```

But the above code closes Modal window, and remains in same details.aspx page. Not redirecting to Report.aspx page. I have tried below code as well,

window.open('../web/Report.aspx');
 This redirects to report.aspx, but page opens in new tab. if i provide _self or _top there is no redirection is performed even in new tab.

I cannot use code behind , have to use Jquery as i need to check which browser is using by the user as below,

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    // Detecting IE
    var oldIE;
    var a_href;
    if ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8, .ie9')) {
        oldIE = true;
    }
    if (oldIE) {        
        a_href = '../web/Report.aspx';
    } else {       
        a_href = '../web/#/user/Report';
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Any informations are most welcome.

Thanks in advance

sangeetha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model form gets closed before reaching window.location.href

Try changing your function like this.

```
 $("[id$=btnQuerySubmit]").bind("click",function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "../web/Report.aspx";
     });
```